# Morphing/contracting under physical force

Tags: physics, soft-body, force-fields

I'm a biologist and I work on cell deformations under stress. I am new to Blender.

As a part of my project, I want to animate/simulate cells deforming under contraction force.

I want to morph/contract differently sized hexagonal prisms (all with the same volume) into a sphere of the same volume. I don't just want to directly morph it but I want to make it in such a way that there is some pulling force at the centre of the hexagonal prism which is pulling it with some (known)force which makes it deform into a sphere. And I want to record the time in which the process will be complete.
[image]

(Pardon my drawing) By contraction force, I mean that the hexagonal prism will collapse under its own force and will morph into a sphere. The blue dot at the centre is the location of the attractive/contractive force which pulls all the sides of the hexagonal prism and forces it to morph into a sphere

My assumption is that different sizes of hexagonal prisms will take different time morph.

Is there a way to do such a thing in Blender? If so, how should I proceed with the workflow for making this?

Please let me know if any more details are needed to answer this question! I'll be glad to provide. Thank You!!!

Comment: Could you add some image about the prisms? Also, what is the force here: some object that drive the prism to sphere morphing?

Comment: Sure! I'll add up the details

Comment: You tagged this with rigid-body-simulation, would soft-body be more appropriate?

Comment: @RonJensen I am a novice in this field so I don't exactly know what is appropriate for this. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll change it.

Comment: https://imgur.com/YnBblsG is this kind of like what you're thinking for a visualization? Strictly morphing, no simulation.

Comment: @RonJensen Yes, I'm looking for exactly this thing but just with physical forces included. Thank you very much;)